# Removing local files Ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

So I'm using Ionic LocalStorage to save some Audios, the record/save function looks like this:

```
startRecord() {
   if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      this.fileName = 'Gravação'+ (this.counter = this.counter + 1);
        this.filePath = this.file.externalDataDirectory.replace(/file:\/\//g, '') + this.fileName;
         this.audio = this.media.create(this.filePath);
```

And the remove function looks like this:

```
 deleteAudio(){
 if (this.platform.is('android')) { 
    this.file.removeFile(this.file.externalDataDirectory, this.fileName)
    }
   }
```

For some reason the delete function doesn't work, and shows nothing on Logs.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How you're calling remove method?

Comment: What do you mean? How the function is activated?

Comment: Yes, from which component you're calling. Can we see code snippet?

Comment: From a simple button: `<ion-button slot="end" (click)="deleteAudio()">
      <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>`